# Span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Nooby question. I just started a Linear Algebra course at my university, had a question about Span{}, is the span of linearly independent vectors always just a line, plane, or 3D space? (Until R3)
Also, how is this concept useful in future material?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's always a subspace. Have you learned about subspaces yet?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's a very application-based course, so we learn very little theory and mostly computational things.

Comment: Hmm, it's a little hard for me to tell how span will be used in future material; I'm more used to a pure treatment of the subject. But yes, the span of a (non-empty) subset of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will always either be $\mathbb{R}^3$, a plane, or a line, the latter two always going through the origin.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Will check out subspaces.